# unity StartCorountine not woking when I call it from another script

Tags: unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I have a IEnumerator with a while loop that should run 100 times that works perfectly when I call this from the start method in the same script. But when I call the IEnumerator from another script it gets called but the while loop only run once.

```
 public class script1: MonoBehaviour
 {
  private void Start()
     {
         //StartCoroutine(StartCountdown(3));
        // When I call it here the while loop runs 100 
     }
  public IEnumerator StartCountdown(float countdownValue)
     {
         float waiteTime = countdownValue / 100;

         int loopNumber = 100;
         //float idk = 0;
         while (loopNumber > 0)
         {
             Debug.Log("aufgerufen");
             circle.fillAmount -= 0.01f;

             yield return new WaitForSeconds(waiteTime);
             loopNumber -= 1;
         }
     }
 }

 public class script2 : MonoBehaviour
 {
 public void GameOver()
     {

         panel.SetActive(true);
         Time.timeScale = 0;

         GameObject circle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("LoadCircle");
         StartCoroutine(circle.GetComponent<LoadCircle>().StartCountdown(3));

         //When  I call it from here the while loop only run once
     }
 }
```

Comment: Do you maybe disable or destroy the `script2`? Note that how you have it the Coroutine will be running on `script2` even though it is defined in `script1`! Otherwise you would need to do `circle.GetComponent<LoadCircle>(). StartCoroutine (circle.GetComponent<LoadCircle>().StartCountdown(3));` in order to run that routine actually on the `script1` or better said `LoadCircle` component

Comment: I find the mistake. In the GameOver Method I set Time.timescale = 0; I dont know why thats effect the IEnumerator but now I know the problem. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
Time.timeScale = 0;
```

but then

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(waiteTime);
```

which is affected by the timescale!

> Suspends the coroutine execution for the given amount of seconds using scaled time.
>
> The real time suspended is equal to the given time divided by `Time.timeScale`

For a timescale = 0 it is not further called at all.

You should use [`WaitForSecondsRealtime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html) instead

```
yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(waiteTime);
```